# jquery post call to a route laravel not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, post

I'm trying to make a jquery post from a JS file to a laravel route but seems like it's not working and I have no idea why.

My main goal here is: get all the IDs from a table that has a checkbox checked and change their column value on SQL.

So, here is my JS function:

```
    function concludeAll() {
        var arrayIds = [];

        $('.checkbox1').each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var $id = $this.attr('id');

            if ($this.is(":checked")) {
                arrayIds.push($id);
            }
        });

        var json = {
            "ids": arrayIds
        };

        $.post('http://localhost:8000/controle/pending/concludeAll',
            {
                '_token': $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content'),
                ids: arrayIds
            })
            .error(

             )
            .success(

             );     
}
```

And this is my route:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/controle'], function() {
Route::post('/pending/concludeAll/', function() {

    $input = Input::only('ids'); 
    $input = $input['ids']; 

    foreach($input as $id) {
        $student = new App\Aluno();
        $student = $student->where('id', '=', $id)->first();
        $student->pending = '0';
        $student->save();
    }

}); };
```

So if I check a few lines on the table and hit the button that calls the function, nothing happens on my console. On network > headers > form data I see the token and the IDs, like this:

> _token:fNWunwF8yDLSycrkBE684wgQcyK9dP8wbR7VgLjC
>   ids[]:23
>   ids[]:20

On preview, I see the exactly same page I am.
On response, I see the HTML of the page.

I also tried a dd($input); on the route, but nothing different happens..

Tried php artisan route:clear and nothing different happens.

If I change the name of the url for http://localhost:8000/controle/pending/concludeAll2, no errors are returned, which makes me crazy...

Any ideas how to make this post call to the route? Thank you!

Comment: Convert your `arrayIds` into JSON `ids: JSON.stringify(arrayIds)` and then see...

Comment: If nothing happens in your console, how can you see those headers?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay the only difference it makes is: On network > headers > form data I see ids:["23","20","29"] instead of ids[]:23 ids[]:20. i think it's necessary, but didn't solve the problem yet. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @Devon nothing on the console, but on Chrome I go to Network > and I see a headers tab.

Comment: @GabrielAugusto, can you do one thing, just put this code `print_r('hi');die;` in your route function and check if you can see `hi` in your network response? Are you sure that its hitting the route function?

Comment: @GabrielAugusto, well, you aren't logging anything to your console so the network tab in Chrome is where you'd see ajax requests...

Comment: I think you should remove `controle` from url: like this 
   `$.post('http://localhost:8000/pending/concludeAll'`

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay I'm so sorry, I forgot to post that the Route above is inside a Route::group('controle').

Comment: ok, what about `print_r('hi');die;` I said to do in my previous comment?

Comment: Ok. I printed 'hi' and inserted die after it. Nothing changed in the Network.

Comment: Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change the route to

```
Route::post('/controle/pending/concludeAll', function() {
    $input = Input::only('ids'); 
    $input = $input['ids']; 
    foreach($input as $id) {
        $student = new App\Aluno();
        $student = $student->where('id', '=', $id)->first();
        $student->pending = '0';
        $student->save();
    }

});
```

and in JS function:

```
    function concludeAll() {
        var arrayIds = [];

        $('.checkbox1').each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var $id = $this.attr('id');

            if ($this.is(":checked")) {
                arrayIds.push($id);
            }
        });
       arrayIds=JSON.stringify(arrayIds);

        var json = {
            "ids": arrayIds
        };

        $.post('http://localhost:8000/controle/pending/concludeAll',
            {
                '_token': $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content'),
                ids: arrayIds
            })
            .error(

             )
            .success(

             );     
    }
```

Comment: I'm so sorry, I forgot to post that the Route above is inside a Route::group('controle').

Comment: @GabrielAugusto can u please post the form, may be that will give some clue. Problem with posting method can also cause similar kind of issue

Comment: I'm sorry, there is no form here. It's a table where I select items and when I hit a normal button, it calls the javascript function which has the post method.